# How many times should I tell ios app user he is on Carrier network?

Tags: ios

According to apple (9.3 and 9.9  https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html ) I need to tell (*doesn´t explicitly say that but that was my understanding*) the user of my app that he is not on a Wifi network and if he streams the content of my app it could cost him lots of money.

**What I can't find out is**:
Do I have to give the user constant warnings e.g *for every link he clicks* **OR** is it enough to just give him warning *one time while he is in the app*? I mean he could be in the app for hours (hopefully :-)).

**EDIT:**
After rereading https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html I see that I have not totally understood the guideline.

**It says :** 
9.3 Audio streaming content over a cellular network may not use more than 5MB over 5 minutes 9.9 Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 64 kbps audio-only HTTP Live stream

So my understanding now is that I would need to *tell the user about the usage after 10 minutes* **OR** *after 5MB download after 5 minutest*? **No that just can´t be! Can it?**

My program is just a container around Youtube streaming video from them.

Comment: You need to find a reference to this requirement. I've had several apps in the store since 2008 and I have never once told the user that they are not on WiFi.

Comment: Dose nobody have clue? Can I skip this warning?